# Metadata being passed with instances create gets overlaid onto the string "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGINlock GMT"

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform

Create the instance with:

```
gcloud compute instances create ...snip
... --metadata empty="",short="foo",long="thirty six character long string bla" ...
```

Then, on the instance, retrieve the metadata with:

```
curl \
    "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/file-name" \
    -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" -silent
```

we end up with

```
empty = X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGINlock GMT
short = foorame-Options: SAMEORIGINlock GMT
long  = thirty six character long string bla
```

I'm not sure if this is a quirk of cURL, google cloud, or just what happens when you serve an extremely short string through http.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was passing -silent rather than --silent as another arg to curl, which was mangling the output.